# admob failed to load:0 on delphi

Tags: delphi, admob

I'm using Delphi 10.2 with admob.

Admob service on Entitlement List is set to true for debug and release configuration and FMX.Advertising  is under USES clause.

Yesterday I created two ad units on admob (one Banner and one Intersticial). The app is linked with Firebase.

I have added a TBanneradd to my form and added the following code:

```
procedure TFrm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   if ad1.AdUnitID='' then
      ad1.AdUnitID:='ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433';  // GOOGLE TEST AD ID
   ad1.LoadAd;
end;
```

**Properties:**

- Adsize: auto
- Align: top

When  I run the app, I get the following error:

> Error 'Ad failed to load: 0'

I'm using the google ad test id because with my own codes I get the same error.

Any idea? Do I have to add anything on androidmanifest manually? if yes, where?

I'm following this embarcadero steps ([Using the AdMob Service](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_the_AdMob_Service#Creating_an_Ad_Unit_for_Your_Application_in_AdMob)) but I'm not able to load any ad.

Thank you.

Comment: After several days my app only shows small banner ads. If I change the unitid by an intersticial ad, it does not show anything. Besides a "Test ad" label is always over the ad.